# How to rearrange the one List same as another list?

Tags: c#

I want to rearrange the list exactly same as another list.

```
List<string> list1= new List<string>();
            list1.Add("a");
            list1.Add("b");
            list1.Add("c");

List<string> list2= new List<string>();
            list2.Add("b");
            list2.Add("c");
            list2.Add("a");
```

Now i want to rearrange the list2 exaclty same as list1 , So after rearranging list2 , it should look like in the same order as list1

Comment: Do we need to check the lists contain the same number of elements first, and identical elements too? If not, we report list 1.

Comment: Can't you assign list2 to list1?

Comment: Seems a very inefficient requirment. List does not copy items. If both the list pointing to same objects, you can just use the first list. Why even create a second list that has exactly the same objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IndexOf` method has O(N) complexity. So, I propose this solution:

```
var list1 = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"};
var list2 = new List<string> {"b", "c", "a"};

var list1Indexes = list1
    .Select((value, index) => (Index: index, Value: value))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Index);

list2 = list2
    .OrderBy(x => list1Indexes.TryGetValue(x, out var index) ? index : -1)
    .ToList();
```

Accessing an element of a dictionary by key is O(1) operation.

Comment: Sorting here is still nlogn, but definetly alot more efficient with O(1) lookups.

Answer (score 4):

Linq approach

```
list2 = list2.OrderBy(list1.IndexOf).ToList();
```

If a item from `list2` doesn't exist in `list1`, it will be placed first, because `IndexOf` returns `-1` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

For lists containing strings, and assuming that the two lists have the same elements in different order, and also assuming that the comparison of the elements is case sensitive, there is no need to keep the original elements. Strings have no hidden identity that needs to be preserved, other than their value. So here you are:

```
list1.Clear();
list1.AddRange(list2);
```